# How to fire off a function at start of a video and a different function when the user pauses and presses play to continue watching the video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, react-hooks, event-handling

Currently, I have a [video.js](https://videojs.com/) player with React. My goal is to fire off a function when the user starts playing the video and to fire a separate function when the user plays the video back again after pausing the video(let's call this the "continue" event). How can I achieve this without firing the incorrect function at start and continue?

I've looked at several different HTML media events such as ['play'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event) and ['playing'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event), however the "continue" function is still firing at start.

Here's what I have:

```
const VideoPlayer = ({ handleOnPlayContinue, handleOnStart }) => {
  const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      videoJSPlayer.on('play'), () => {
        setHasStarted(true);
      };
      videoJSPlayer.on('playing'), () => {
        handleOnPlayContinue();
      };
    }, [videoJSPlayer, handleOnPlayContinue]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasStarted) {
      handleOnStart();
    }
  }, [hasStarted, handleOnStart]);
}
```

Should I be toggling another boolean state on 'pause' and use that boolean flag to fire my continue function? I thought of setting another state to manage when the user is continuing the video after pausing, but wanted to know if there's another HTML media event that I can leverage.

Thanks for any tips and answers you may have!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a relevant HTML media event; you are going to have to manage it yourself with state and within just the `play` event. See if the below works for what you are trying to achieve (I have not been able to test it). Keep in mind that changes to state in `useEffect` aren't updated synchronously, and `hasStarted` needs to be in the dependency array otherwise the event will reference stale state variables. We also want to clean up event listeners between `useEffect` calls.

```
const VideoPlayer = ({ handleOnPlayContinue, handleOnStart }) => {
  const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    videoJSPlayer.on("play", () => {
      if (!hasStarted) {
        handleOnStart();
        setHasStarted(true);
      } else {
        handleOnPlayContinue();
      }
    });
    return () => {
      videoJSPlayer.off("play");
    };
  }, [hasStarted, handleOnPlayContinue, handleOnStart, videoJSPlayer]);
};
```